# Viscous flow inside a rotating cylinder for $t>0$ if rotation is stopped at $t=0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, mathematics

There is an infintely long cylinder of radius $a$ which is filled completely with a fluid with viscosity $\mu$ and density $\rho$ and was rotating with a constant angular velocity $\Omega$ for time $t<0$. At $t=0$ the cylinder is abruputly stopped and the question is to calculate the velocity field inside it for $t>0$.

I started with the Navier-Stokes equation in cylindrical coordinates which are:

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(ru_r) + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (u_\theta) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u_z) = 0,$$

$$\rho \left(\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial t} + u_r \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial t}  + \frac{u_{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta} + u_z \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z} - \frac{u_\theta^2}{r}\right) = -\frac{\partial P}{\partial r} + \mu \left(\nabla^2 u_r -\frac{u_r}{r^2} - \frac{2}{r^2}\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial \theta}\right) + \rho g_r,$$

$$\rho \left(\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial t} + u_r \frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial t}  + \frac{u_{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial \theta} + u_z \frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial z} + \frac{u_r u_\theta}{r}\right) = -\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} + \mu \left(\nabla^2 u_\theta -\frac{u_\theta}{r^2} + \frac{2}{r^2}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta}\right) + \rho g_\theta,$$

$$\rho \left(\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial t} + u_r \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial t}  + \frac{u_{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial \theta} + u_z \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z} \right) = -\frac{\partial P}{\partial z} + \mu \left(\nabla^2 u_\theta \right) + \rho g_z,$$

where $\nabla^2 \equiv \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$.

I made the assumption that the flow is purely along the $\hat{\theta}$ direction so the radial ($u_r$) and vertical ($u_z$) velocity components will be indentically zero. This also implies (from the first equation) that the derivative $\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial\theta}=0$. I also assume $\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} = 0$ since no force acts along $\hat\theta$ direction. Gravity is acting along the $-z$ direction so $g_r = g_\theta =0$ and $g_z = -g$. Under these assumptions the above system then reduces to

$$-\frac{u_\theta^2}{r} = -\frac{\partial P}{\partial r},$$
$$\rho \frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial t} = \frac{\mu}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r}\right),$$
$$ 0 = -\frac{\partial P}{\partial z} - \rho g,$$

where $u_\theta \equiv u_\theta(r,t)$.

The third equation above can be solved as $P(r,z) = -\rho g z + f(r)$ where $f(r)$ is an function of integration. $f(r)$ can be solved for by plugging into the first equation if we know what $u_\theta$ is. And $u_\theta$ can be solved for from the second equation. So, it seems we have sufficient number of equations and unknowns.

The boundary condition and initial that I impose on $u_\theta(r,t)$ is $u(r,0) = \Omega r$  and $u(0,t) = 0$. I assumed them because they seem reasonable to me but I do not know if these are the right boundary conditions.

I tried solving the PDE in the second equation by separation of variables. Letting $u_\theta(r,t) = R(r) T(t)$ it reduces to

$$\frac{T'(t)}{\nu T(t)} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{R'(r) + r R''(r)}{R(r)} = -\lambda^2 <0,$$

where $\nu = \mu/\rho$. The boundary condition for $R(r)$ that I impose is $R(0)=0$. I chose to equate them to a negative constant ($-\lambda^2$) because I want the flow to decay in time.

The ODE we get for $R(r)$ is actually the Bessel ODE of order $0$. This means that imposing $R(0) = 0$ will make the solution identically zero i.e., $R(r)\equiv0$. If instead I assume a different boundary condition that $R(a)=0$ (again not sure if it's physical) then I can actually pin down what $\lambda$ can be using the zeros of the Bessel function.

But even with this different boundary condition, it still is quite a questionable solution because $J_0(r\lambda)$ is an oscillatory function but I physically do not expect any oscillations in the solution. I expect an exponential kind of decay and as time goes to infinity the fluid dissipates energy and becomes stationary.

I need some help/suggestions about what I am doing/assuming wrong in this problem. Thank you.

Comment: The BC hat r = 0 should be R'(0)=0.  Also, should the expansion be in terms of $J_1$; at least that's what I get.

Comment: https://oceanofmath.blog/?p=212